# Ruby rails how do i show if boolean is false or true

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In Ruby on Rails how do I show some html if boolean is false or true?

Like if boolean false show:

```
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>

if true

<p>active</p>

else

<p>not active</p>

<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's what those `<% %>` tags you're using do, they're for embedded Ruby.

```
<% if true %>
  <p> active</p>
<% else %>
  <p>not active</p>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
<% if some_condition %>
  <p>active</p>
<% else %> 
  <p>not active</p>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that this way:

```
<% if true %>
  <p>active</p>
<% else %>
  <p>not active</p>
<% end %>
```

or

```
<p><%= 'not ' if true %>active</p>
```

or

```
<p><%= "#{'not ' unless true}active" %></p>
```

or

```
<p><%= if true then 'active' else 'not active' end %></p>
```

*Note: remember that `"#{nil}"` equals to `""` (nil values are escaped to empty strings)*